# Minimize total cost to buy unique products over timespan

Tags: modeling, python, integer-programming

I am looking for some guidance on how to better state my problem formally and practically (e.g., relevant Python libraries).

Let's assume I have a set of $X$ unique products to buy. I have $Y$ days in total to buy them, and I can only buy a fraction $Z$ of these products per day. The price of the product may vary with each day. My main constraint is that I can only buy each product once. An optional constraint is that I cannot buy a product above a price $W$. The objective is to buy as much of these unique products as possible (ideally $X$) by minimizing the total cost of the operation.

Here is some very simple sample data, assuming I can only buy two products a day, looking to minimize the total cost at buying all 4 products over those 3 days.

```
Product   Cost, D1   Cost, D2   Cost, D3
  A          05         19         12   
  B          54         24         32
  C          89         04         56 
  D          31         78         21
```

Where should I start looking?

**First edit**: I am working on the mathematical formulation, and I also have been reading on similar problems. It does look similar to an assignment problem, with the difference that the amount of jobs (here, the different days/costs) and workers (products) is not symmetrical. Is this an apt observation? Would duplicating the jobs, [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45807471), be a possible solution?

Comment: I would recommend first writing out the mathematical formulation as that is universal.  Then, it is simply a matter of translating into code.

Comment: In formulating your mathematical model, start by asking yourself what decisions you have to make, creating a variable for each decision. Then ask yourself what limits your decisions (each limitation becomes a constraint), and finally ask how you would choose among competing solutions (the criterion becomes your objective function).

Comment: Thank you both. I am trying to come up with a mathematical formulation indeed. I also have been trying to find similar problems, and it does look very close to the job/worker assignment problem, where one job is available to multiple workers — would you agree?